# AngularJS Variable is Undefined

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope, undefined

So my code looks like this

```
.controller('weinDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$rootScope',function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $rootScope) {

$scope.url = "https://winetastic.azurewebsites.net/tables/Wine/" + $rootScope.actWine + "?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0";
$scope.Winet;

$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: $scope.url
}).then(function mySucces(response) {

    $scope.wineDetails = response.data;
    $scope.Winet = $scope.wineDetails.Winetype_ID;
    alert($scope.Winet);


}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.wineDetails = response.statusText
});

alert($scope.Winet);}])
```

the first alert gave me the right WineType_ID, the second alert give me an 'Undefined'.
What's wrong?

Comment: first alert will be `undefine` and second will be having value

Comment: Yes you are right, but why? I want to do further sutff with winet, but it always says it's undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clear you your first alert will be `undefined` and second will be having value.

This is because you will not have `$scope.Winet` value when it will call for first time. Once you get the value from the server then it will have some value. This is what **Asynchronous** is all about.

For time being you can use assign some value to `$scope.Winet`. so first time alert will be that value instead of undefined.
Try

```
$scope.url = "https://winetastic.azurewebsites.net/tables/Wine/" + $rootScope.actWine + "?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0";
$scope.Winet = 'alert before Asynchronous call completion';//you can change it as your need
```

Now first time alert will be `alert before Asynchronous call completion`.

More detials you can go to this link.

[**Asynchronous Details**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score 1):

Your second alert is called before getting data from REST call. This is due to the asynchronous nature of javaScript. So you are getting value as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Winetype_ID` is undefined in your `response.data`, check your response data. And I'd suggest using `console.log();` so your script doesn't halt.